# PHP Postback URL

Tags: php, postback

I would like to know how to get variables from postback url so I can insert them into database.

Example:

[mywebsite.com/postback.php](http://mywebsite.com/postback.php)

When something is done on other website and not mine, website pings me back like:

[mywebsite.com/postback.php?id=3&token=391](http://mywebsite.com/postback.php?id=3&token=391)

What exactly now do I need to put in postback.php file so I can get those variables and use them to update the database I'm connected to?

Comment: Connect to mysql. Insert a record, binding variables `$_GET['id']` and `$_GET['token']`. Profit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response from the other website is a basic GET request
You can access those variables in your `postback.php` file with the `$_GET` var

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$token = $_GET['token'];

(SQL Insert there)
```